# Condition in SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I've got an SQL-script executed by SQL*Plus, that needs to run with *Oracle 10g* and *Oracle 11g*.

That script gives grants on a package that does not exist before 11g:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_result_cache TO my_user;
```

I would like to avoid the exception on 10g, since I want to react to other exceptions in the script.

---

One way is to use [**Conditional Compilation**](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-jul/o46plsql.html) and [`dbms_db_version`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_dbver.htm):

```
BEGIN
  $IF dbms_db_version.ver_le_10 $THEN NULL; $ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_result_cache TO my_user';
  $END
END;
/
```

Is there any other way, preferable without using PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question and one of the comments indicate that you want to avoid PL/SQL blocks and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I also assume that by "react to other exceptions" you mean abort execution of the script when an exception is encountered.

If so, I think the best you can do in pure SQL/SQL*Plus is to ignore the exception exit for the grant statement:

```
... first part of script (with exit on sqlerror in effect)
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_result_cache TO my_user;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
... remaining part of script
```

Comment: Thanks! This would work too. Since it would never fail though (even if I write invalid code) I guess I'm going to stick with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the object exists beforehand:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT NULL
                FROM all_objects
               WHERE owner = 'SYS'
                 AND object_name = 'DBMS_RESULT_CACHE'
                 AND ROWNUM = 1) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_result_cache TO my_user';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat: True, but it still would involve PL/SQL and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`...

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I don't think you can simulate a branching algorithm using only SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate branching by writing SQL that generates SQL and spools it to a sql script. Then run the sql script:

```
define temp_file='somefile.sql'

set heading off
set feedback off
spool &&temp_file

SELECT 'GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_result_cache TO my_user;'
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE owner = 'SYS'
   AND object_name = 'DBMS_RESULT_CACHE';

spool off
@&&temp_file
host rm &&temp_file
```

Thanks to @Vincent for the data dictionary query.